# How to draw a mesh from .obj file on a ID2D1DeviceContext object?

Tags: c++, directx

I have a mesh object saved in .obj file and I want to draw the mesh using ID2D1DeviceContext object.
I cannot find any examples on the net that does this.
I know how to fill simple things like:

```
// Create a solid color D2D brush.
ComPtr<ID2D1SolidColorBrush> brush;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    m_d2dContext->CreateSolidColorBrush(
        DX::ConvertToColorF(color),
        &brush
        )
    );

// Draw a filled rectangle.
m_d2dContext->FillRectangle(DX::ConvertToRectF(rect), brush.Get());
```

But I want to display something elegant. How do I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Search for `.obj parser` and make a structure of mesh that contains 3D attributes/vertices.

Comment: You don't use Direct2D to draw a 3D mesh object. You use Direct3D for that. Take a look at Model in [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).